# PHP Validation. It won't go to display page

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm new to PHP and the validation. I have been asked by my lecturer to make a form with session and validation.I have 3 php pages such as `pbt1.php , pbt2.php and validation.php` After all validated, it will go to display page. However, it seems like it only stopped at validation page [`validation.php`]. I need someone to check if my codes are correct or wrong too.
`pbt1.php`

```
session_start();
?>
<html>
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['pbt1']))
{
    $nameError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'];  
    $numberError    =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'];
    $cityError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError'];
    $addressError   =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError'];
    $zipcodeError   =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError'];
    $dateError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'];
}
?>

<style>
.registrationform 
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    border: solid 3px red;   
}

Label
{
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}

</style>

    <div class= "registrationform">

        <h1>ONLINE MARATHON REGISTRATION</h1>
        <br><br>

        <form name = "pbt1" method = "post" action = "validation.php">
        
        <Label>Name<span style="color: red;">*</span>: </Label>
        <input type = "text" name = "name">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;" > <?php echo isset($nameError)?$nameError :'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Gender <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Female" required>Female
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Male" required>Male
        <br><br>

        <Label>Date Of Birth <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "date" name = "date">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($dateError)?$dateError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Contact Number <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "phonenumber">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($numberError)?$numberError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Address <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label>
        <input type = "text" name = "address" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($addressError)?$addressError :'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>City <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "city" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($cityError)?$cityError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <Label>Zip Code <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</Label> 
        <input type = "text" name = "zipcode" >
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"><?php echo isset($zipcodeError)?$zipcodeError:'';?></span>
        <br><br>

        <div style="text-align:center;">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name="Submit">
        </div>
        </form>
        
    </div>

    <br><br>
</html>
```

`pbt2.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<style>
    table 
{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>



<div style="background-color:cyan;">

<h1 align = 'center'> YOUR INFORMATION AS THE TABLE BELOW </h1>

<table width = '400' border = '1' align = 'center'>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['name'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['phonenumber'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['address'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['city'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip Code</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['zipcode'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['gender'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['Userdata']['date'];?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
</html>
```

`validation.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(isset($name) && empty($name))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError']="Name must be required!";
        header('location:pbt1.php');  
        
    }
    else
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
        {
            $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            header('location:pbt1.php');  
            
        }   
    }

    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    if(isset($phonenumber) && empty($phonenumber))
        {
            $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] = "Error, insert phone number";
            header('location:pbt1.php');  
            
        }
    else 
        {
            if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]*)$/', $phonenumber))
            {
                $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] = "Numbers only";
                header('location:pbt1.php');  
                
            }
        }
    
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    if(isset($address) && empty($address))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError'] = "Error, enter your address";
        header('location:pbt1.php');
        
    }

    $city = $_POST['city'];
    if(isset($city) && empty($city))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError'] = "Error, enter your city";
        header('location:pbt1.php');
        
    }

    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    if(isset($zipcode) && empty($zipcode))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError'] = "Error, enter your zipcode";
        header('location:pbt1.php');
        
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!preg_match('/^([0-9]*)$/', $zipcode))
        {
            $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError'] = "Numbers only";
            header('location:pbt1.php');  
            
        }
    }

    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $date = $_POST['date'];
    if(isset($date) && empty($date))
    {
        $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'] = "Error, select the date";
        header('location:pbt1.php');
    }

    $_SESSION['Userdata'] = ['name'=>$name ,'phonenumber'=>$phonenumber,'address'=>$address,'city'=>$city,
                            'zipcode'=>$zipcode,'gender'=>$gender,'date'=>$date ];

}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if($_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'] == "" && $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] == "" && $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError']== "" && $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError']=="" && $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError']=="" && $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError']=="")
    {
    header("location:pbt2.php");
    exit; }
?>
```

Comment: Hi ! When you execute function `header()`, it won't stop the execution of the code, even if it's `header('Location...')`. You should add a `exit` or `die()` instruction right after to prevent weird behaviors

Comment: Where to put that actually if you see my code? @Zyigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the PHP version (>= 7.0) you are using, you could change

```php
<?php echo isset($nameError)?$nameError :'';?>
```

to

```php
<?php echo $nameError ?? ''; ?>
```

As for HTML, you might want to change

```html
<form name = "pbt1" method = "post" action = "validation.php">
```

to

```html
<form name="pbt1" method="post" action="validation.php">
```

That doesn't change the outcome, but easier to read.

What's next...

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(isset($name) && empty($name))
{
```

could be changed into

```php
if (array_key_exists('name', $_POST) && trim($_POST['name']) === '') {
```

Looks like more code, but the intention of the `if` becomes more clear.

As far as this one goes

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['pbt1']))
{
    $nameError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'];  
    $numberError    =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'];
    $cityError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError'];
    $addressError   =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError'];
    $zipcodeError   =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError'];
    $dateError      =   $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'];
}
```

...don't trust your session. I would change it to

```php
if (array_key_exists('pbt1', $_SESSION)) {
    $nameError    = $_SESSION['pbt1']['nameError'] ?? '';  
    $numberError  = $_SESSION['pbt1']['numberError'] ?? '';
    $cityError    = $_SESSION['pbt1']['cityError'] ?? '';
    $addressError = $_SESSION['pbt1']['addressError'] ?? '';
    $zipcodeError = $_SESSION['pbt1']['zipcodeError'] ?? '';
    $dateError    = $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'] ?? '';
}
```

This one

```php
    $_SESSION['Userdata'] = ['name'=>$name ,'phonenumber'=>$phonenumber,'address'=>$address,'city'=>$city,
                            'zipcode'=>$zipcode,'gender'=>$gender,'date'=>$date ];
```

I would change to

```php
    $_SESSION['Userdata'] = [
        'name'        => $_POST['name'] ?? '', 
        'phonenumber' => $_POST['phonenumber'] ?? '',
        'address'.    => $_POST['address'] ?? '',
        'city'.       => $_POST['city'] ?? '',
        'zipcode'     => $_POST['zipcode'] ?? '',
        'gender'.     => $_POST['gender'] ?? '',
        'date'.       => $_POST['date'] ?? '',
    ];
```

Since `validation.php` is pure PHP, get rid of

```php
?>
```

at the end of the file.

What else...
At the beginning of `validation.php`, make sure you clear out `$_SESSION['pbt1']` aka.

```php
unset($_SESSION['pbt1']);
```

Instead of doing `header('location:pbt1.php');` after every issue, remove `header('location:pbt1.php');` from every individual `if` block and put it at the end, as in

```php
if(isset($date) && empty($date)) {
    $_SESSION['pbt1']['dateError'] = "Error, select the date";
    // header('location:pbt1.php');
}

if (array_key_exists('pbt1', $_SESSION)) {
    header('location:pbt1.php');
    exit;
}

    $_SESSION['Userdata'] = ...
```

that way you don't have to fix every error by itself and you show them all at once.

Comment: I followed this and somehow I got this error `UncaughtArgumentCountError:` in pbt1.php line 7. How to fix that?

Comment: Could you show us this line 7?